# I am seeking a solution using Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem to prove that $|S|=0$, and $|\cdot|$ means Lebesgue measure.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $S$ be a measurable subset of $\Bbb{R^2}$. Assume for every $x\in S$ there exists a sequence of cubes $\{Q_k(x)\}$ centered at $x$ with side lengths tending to zero such that $$|S\cap Q_k(x) |\le\frac{1}{2}|Q_k(x)|$$ Show that $|S|=0$

I found that $\{Q_k(x)\}$ is a Vitali covering, so we have $|S\setminus\bigcup Q_j|=0$ and $\sum Q_j<(1+\epsilon)|S|$. 
Then $$|S|=|S\setminus \bigcup Q_j|+|\bigcup Q_j \cap S|=0+\sum |Q_j\cap S| \le \frac{1}{2}\sum |Q_j|$$

By $\sum Q_j<(1+\epsilon)|S|$ and let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, then $|S|<\frac{3}{4}|S|$, so contradiction. Thus $|S|=0$.

However, my teacher particularly pointed out that we can use the Lebesgue Differentiation theorem.

Could anyone kindly provide a hint on how to use the Lebesgue Diffrentiaion theorem here? Thanks!

Comment: Please note that one can write $|\cdot|$ and $3\cdot5$ and $3\times5$, so there is no need to use an asterisk for those purposes.  An asterisk is a workaround for occasions when one is limited to the symbols on the keyboard.  Also $S\backslash\bigcup Q_j$ looks different from $S\setminus\bigcup Q_j$ and I changed it to the latter.  That's because binary operation symbols provide spacing to the left and right. (Notice that $+5$ doesn't have the same space between "$+$" and "$5$" that $3+5$ has, and there's a reason for that.) Also${}\,\ldots{}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$"$\cup$" is used in expressions like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ and "$\bigcup$" is used in things like $\bigcup\limits_j Q_j$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelHardy Hi, Michael. Do you have any idea about how to prove this using Lebesgue differentiation theorem?

Comment: I'd have to review that, but I'm guessing the theorem would be applied to the indicator function of $S$, i.e. $\chi_S(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x\in S, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$ ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $\chi_S(x)$, the indicator function of $S$.  By Lebesgue's differentiaton theorem,

$\lim_{|Q| \to 0} \frac{1}{|Q|} \int_Q \chi_S = \chi_S(x)$ for ae $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Note that $\frac{1}{|Q|} \int_Q \chi_S = \frac{|Q \cap S|}{|Q|}$.

Suppose $|S| > 0$.  Then we can find an $x \in S$ such that the conclusion of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem holds when applied to $\chi_S$ at $x$.  That is,

$\lim_{|Q| \to 0} \frac{1}{|Q|} \int_Q \chi_s  = 1$.

However, by assumption there's a sequence $Q_k$ of cubes whose sidelengths tend to $0$ with $|S \cap Q_k| \le \frac{1}{2} |Q_k|$.

From the above limit, choose $k$ sufficiently large so that $\frac{1}{|Q_k|} \int_{Q_k} \chi_S > \frac{1}{2}$.

Evaluating the integral as above and using the bound on $|S \cap Q_k|$ gives a contradiction.